# Vagrantfile setup with multi-cluster

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I'm looking to use Vagrant to create several but identical cluster of VMs.

For example, suppose I want to create 2 VMs, say with hostnames `n1` and `n2` as one cluster (`clusterA`). Then I want to basically repeat the same identical setup, but name the next 2 VMs as `n3` and `n4` on a second cluster (`clusterB`). The two clusters have exact identical setups (i.e. # of disks, network setup, rpms and packages installed, etc...), however have 2 separate identities.

In some cases I might to make small modifications to each cluster.

What is a clean way to organize the Vagrantfiles? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.

First, I created a shell script in the base project folder `create-cluster.sh`.  This script will take a cluster name as an input and do the following:

1. `mkdir ./$cluster_name`
2. `cp ./Vagrantfile-template  ./$cluster_name`
   `cp ./settings.yaml ./$cluster_name`
   (copy any other settings files here, i.e. settings.yaml)
3. `cd ./$cluster_name` <-- i.e. clusterA, clusterB, etc...
4. `vagrant up`

So you end up with the following directories:

```
myproject/
|--- create-cluster.sh
|--- delete-cluster.sh
|--- Vagrantfile-template
|--- settings.yaml
|--- <any other external files required to build VM>
|
|--- clusterA
|    |-- Vagrantfile (copied from ../Vagrantfile-template)
|
|--- clusterB
|    |-- Vagrantfile (copied from ../Vagrantfile-template)
```

The Vagrantfile-template loads the settings.yaml file to import any unique settings.  This way the Vagrantfile can be written to support any number of nodes, disks, etc...  For example:

settings.yaml:

```
---
num-nodes: 2
```

Vagrantfile-tempale:

```
require "yaml"
$settings = YAML.load_file "settings.yaml"
num_nodes = $settings['num-nodes']

# Customize configuration specific settings
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "centos/8"
    (1..num_nodes).each do |i|
        config.vm.define node-#{i} do |node|
            node.vm.hostname = node#{i}

        <other common setup, i.e. provisioners>
    end
end
```

This approach allows a common Vagrantfile setup, but yet allows you to separately manage each cluster, i.e. `vagrant halt`, `vagrant destroy`, etc...